# What was the riddle given by Bill Wilkins?

Tags: the-conjuring-universe, the-conjuring-2

In *The Conjuring 2*, what was the riddle given by Bill Wilkins to solve? What was its answer and significance in the film?

Comment: The solution ("your name") is clearly stated and explained in the movie.

Comment: yeah why would Valak want Lorraine to know her name unless she wanted her to find her and cast her back to hell

Comment: I thought the answer was "your shadow", although I wasn't able to correlate its meaning to the film.

Answer (score 8):

The Riddle was:

> I am given and I am taken.
>   I was there at your first breath,
>   But you didn't ask for me.
>   But I will follow you till your death.

The Answer was **name**. That is what was needed for them to beat the demon, they needed to know the demons name which will give them power over him.

Answer (score 2):

> I am given and I am taken.
>   I was there at your first breath,
>   But you didn't ask for me.
>   But I will follow you till your death.

Many say the answer is "name".

However I prefer "Faith".

They knew the mechanic of the demon's name before the meeting with Bill and as a result were seeking its name. I feel Bill eludes to Lorraine's faith which resides in her Bible where she also finds the name of the demon.

Comment: But from the perspective of film the answer was name.

Answer (score 1):

I am given and I am taken.
I was there at your first breath,
But you didn't ask for me.
But I will follow you till your death.
Many say the answer is "name".

However I prefer "Faith".

They knew the mechanic of the demon's name before the meeting with Bill and as a result were seeking its name. I feel Bill eludes to Lorraine's faith which resides in her Bible where she also finds the name of the demon.